# How to convert SELECT statement to Eloquent?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

This works in existing website, trying to convert to Laravel 5.8 code:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y') AS 'article',
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m')AS 'm',
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') AS 'y',
  COUNT(id) AS 'total'
FROM posts
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%M')
ORDER BY m DESC
```

I tried:

```php
$archives = DB::select("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y') AS 'article',DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m')AS 'm', DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') AS 'y', COUNT(id) AS 'total' FROM posts GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%M') ORDER BY m DESC");`
```

I got:

> Error:  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'amohdb.posts.created_at' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT
>   DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y') AS 'article',DATE_FORMAT(created_at,
>   '%m')AS 'm', DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y') AS 'y', COUNT(id) AS 'total'
>   FROM posts GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%M') ORDER BY m DESC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be much simpler than I thought

```
$archives =  Post::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y') as article"),
DB::raw("COUNT(id) as total"))
->groupBy('article')
->get();
```